# How to load a combobox with vaadin fusion

Tags: java, typescript, combobox, vaadin

Hi I'm using the vaadin starter in order to learn more about vaadin.

I just started a new project (Java+Typescript)

I am having issues to solve an issue.

I have a `Users` and `Rol` Entity, being `Rol` an attribute of `User`, the thing is when I am setting the views created with vaading start I am trying to set up a combo box to load Roles to be used to create a new user but nothing work so far.

In the tutorial in vaading web page they solve this in a way that is way different to the arch and files created by the vaadin start so I thought that maybe would be another way to do it.

My entities

User

```
package com.example.application.data.entity;

import com.vaadin.fusion.Nonnull;
import com.example.application.data.AbstractEntity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;



@Entity
public class Users extends AbstractEntity {


    @ManyToOne
    @Nonnull
    private Rol rol;

    
    public Rol getRol() {
        return rol;
    }
    public void setRol(Rol rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

}
```

Rol

```
package com.example.application.data.entity;

import com.vaadin.fusion.Nonnull;
import com.example.application.data.AbstractEntity;
import javax.persistence.Entity;


@Entity
public class Rol extends AbstractEntity{
    
    @Nonnull
    private String name;

    @Nonnull
    private String description;

    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

What should I do to load this with all roles in order to select one in my `users-view.ts`

`<vaadin-combo-box label="Rol" id="rol" ${field(this.binder.model.rol)} item-label-path="name"></vaadin-combo-box>`

Right now I'getting this

[How the combobox shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rueen.png)

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I made it, the thing is that was a problem caused by my lack of skills on typescrypt languaje. the thing is that I did my research and could do it.

`@state()
  private status: Status[] = [];` just added this line and use a method to get all the items from the `StatusRepository.java`

Comment: Can you formulate your solution as answer to this question, so that it is not being left hanging unresolved. It is perfectly ok to answer own questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Solution was:

added tis lines to my typescrypt class

```
@state()
private roles: Rol[] = [];
```

`@state` from `'lit/decorators.js'`

then in the `connectedCallback` function added this line

```
this.roles = await RolesEndpoint.listAll();
```

`listAll()` is a method that I created on my endpint class.

like this:

```
@Nonnull
public List<@Nonnull Rol> listAll() {
   return service.listAll();
}
```

and in my service class

```
public List<Rol> listAll() {
   return repository.findAll();
}
```

Now you can call the data in your combobox element

```
<vaadin-combo-box .items=${this.roles} label="Rol" id="rol"  ${field(this.binder.model.rol)} item-label-path="name" item-value-path="id"></vaadin-combo-box>
```

I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: If I have a list of simple Strings then how to populate it?
just by giving .items=${this.mylist} ? or any other thing would require?

Comment: @kushalBaldev yes you can do that, the thing in this particular case is that I needed to. load from DB to get all the items. but if it is already created on the ts file you can do it. directly.